# Set display resolution from CMD or powershell using inbuilt command on windows

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

I am looking for native windows command to change the resolution on windows 10 system. I trolled through many articles and all talks about using a third party tool like QRes, etc.

Do we have an inbuilt command line utility to change the resolution of the desktop from cmd or PowerShell?

Comment: There is no such utility. It can be done from PowerShell, but only by compiling some C# code. For example, [this](https://superuser.com/a/877483).

Comment: Wish windows developer come up with something on this missing feature. Any idea why the functionality is not there?

Comment: Because allowing applications to futz with a global setting like resolution is a bad idea in general -- the user has no trouble doing it from the UI (covering 99% of the use cases outside games), but experience has shown that applications will happily abuse whatever options you give them in order to make life better for themselves (or so they think) with no consideration to the impact on the rest of the system -- or, indeed, sometimes, the user. This is one thing that probably doesn't need an easily accessible command line tool; the Win32 functions are enough for those who really need it.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert for the elaborated answer to my query. I guess this quite reasonable for developers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no in-built tool with Windows 10 that will allow you to change the resolution automatically.

I tried automating resolution using direct registry edits with PowerShell, but there are too many different possible keys responsible for it, depending on the type of graphics card you have.

If you can find the exact registry keys responsible for your resolution, you could use cmdlets such as *Get-PSDrive -PSProvider Registry,New-ItemProperty,Get-Item,Get-ItemProperty,Set-ItemProperty,Remove-Item,Remove-ItemProperty* to automate that.

To find the registry keys in question, there are a number of approaches. You could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to look at which registry keys and files are being updated when you make a resolution change.

Or you could regedit to export the registry before and after you make the change, and then compare the two files using a tool such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en)

Comment: Looks very tedious. I would give it a try though.